# Akka http and ReactiveMongo error

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, reactivemongo

I have a HTTP API that stream documents from a mongodb and calculate some aggregates. Actually the following code doesn't start if the mongodb isn't available or stop if the mongodb get in troubles after the HTTP server has start.

```scala
val collection : Future[BSONCollection]= driver.connection(mongoUri).get.database(databaseName).map(_.collection(collectionName))

// Akka Stream source used to stream KPIs from randomCDR objects read in mongodb
val kpisSource : Source[Kpis,NotUsed] = mongodbCdrSource(collection,materializer)
  .viaMat(aggregateByWayAndType)(Keep.right)

logger.info("Starting stream API")

val route =
  // the path used to get KPIs
  path("kpi") {
    get {
      // provide the HTTP response by completing and materializing the KPIs source
      complete(kpisSource)
    }
  }

val serverBinding: Future[ServerBinding] = Http().bindAndHandle(route,httpHost)

serverBinding.failed.foreach { ex =>
  logger.error("{}, Failed to bind to {}:{}!",ex,httpHost,httpPort)
}
```

It seems ReactiveMongo errors are not critical and the driver tries to continually connect to the MongoDB.

What would be the best way to

1. start the server even if the MongoDB isn't available ?
2. continue to serve HTTP request even if the MongoDB fails after the HTTP server start ? Probably an `ExceptionHandler` from the routing DSL ?

**edit**

Modifying the code as below allows the HTTP server to start and send a custom error message when MongoDB isn't reachable. But I am still encountering an issue when the MongoDB becomes unavailable after some successful HTTP request. No exception is raised and I just get an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. When MongoDB comes back, the HTTP server can server request again...

```scala
// assign connection to a val to reuse it each time and minimize creation cost
val connection = driver.connection(mongoUri)
// don't assign collection to a val to be able to recover a connection failure
def collection : Future[BSONCollection] = connection.get.database(databaseName).map(_.collection(collectionName))

// Akka Stream source used to stream KPIs from randomCDR objects read in mongodb
def kpisSource : Source[Kpis,NotUsed] = mongodbCdrSource(collection,materializer)
  .viaMat(aggregateByWayAndType)(Keep.right)

val mongodbExceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
  case _ : PrimaryUnavailableException =>
    complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = "Failed to connect to mongodb primary !"))
  case _ =>
    complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = "Failed to connect to mongodb !"))
}

logger.info("Starting stream API")

val route =
  // the path used to get KPIs
  handleExceptions(mongodbExceptionHandler) {
    path("kpi") {
      get {
        // provide the HTTP response by completing and materializing the KPIs source
        complete(kpisSource)
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my source. I suspect it to not raise any exception but just complete the `Future[State]` with a failure ???

```scala
def mongodbCdrSource(collection : Future[BSONCollection],mat: ActorMaterializer): Source[RandomCdr,Future[State]]= {
    implicit val materializer = mat
    implicit val executionContext = materializer.executionContext

    val zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault
    val day = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond()*1000L
    val selector = BSONDocument("dateTime" -> BSONDocument("$gt" -> day))
    Await.result(collection,5.second).find(selector).cursor[RandomCdr](ReadPreference.nearest).documentSource()
}
```

Comment: As indicated in the documentation, assigning connection/DB resolution to `val` is a bad practice preventing any recovery in case of server/network temporary issue

Comment: Misses it. Little correction: connection can be assigned to val but DB and collection should not